# Dynamic I²C address

Tags: microcontroller, i2c

I'm having a problem with a system I'm designing that should support multiple modules, these modules communicate over the I²C bus and all have their own micro-controller which takes care of their own address.

As I don't want the users to have to specify the address using dip-switches, the micro-controller should detect the assigned address (in EEPROM) and if it's the default address it should query the master for a unique address. This works when you connect only one module at a time, but when all the modules are connected at once they will all listen to the same address.

Therefore, I thought of using a I²C repeater (PCA9514adp, or similar), which I can enable or disable (which will basically disable the SDA/SCL out of the IC). The micro-controller will disable the bus when it detects the default I²C address and after querying the master for a unique address it will reset and open the bus so that the next module can request a unique address.

The problem I'm having now is that the data-sheet specifies that I shouldn't use more than 3 repeater on the bus and that's simply not enough so I guess that idea can be put in the bin...

So I guess my question is: how can I disable the I²C bus, so that only one module listens to the default I²C address at the same time, but without the limitations of the I²C repeater?

Comment: Unfortunately you've hit one of the problems that I2C was not designed to solve.

Comment: How are the modules connected? Are they daisy chained together? In other words, can one module (say 'a') connect to the main board, then the next module (say 'b') connects to the first module 'a'.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Actually, the multiple-master protocol handles this just fine.

Comment: @TomCarpenter The modules are indeed daisy chained together. My initial plan was to have each microcontroller act as a master, so that we have a master-slave/master configuration. The microcontroller in turn toggles the i2c repeater so that the chain can be broken in order to allow the address assignment by the 'master-master'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you were thinking of using an I²C repeater (PCA9514adp), it would be easier to use a handshake signal that depends upon connection order. This would be daisy chained, so two pins, an input (from previous) and an output (to next).

Comment: I'm not sure i'm following you... The two pins you're describing, I suppose you mean other pins than the SCL and SDA? That does make some sense, since i'm using microcontrollers as the brains for the modules...

Comment: Yes, an additional two pins, you would have had to use one additional pin to control the repeater.

Comment: +1. Given the slaves are MCUs, you could also use the reset pin so as not to use any additional I/O pins. Each module has an output (what would have been the control signal of the PCA) which connects to the reset pin of the next module (with pull-down resistor). When each module is released from reset by the previous module, it would keep the rest of the chain held in reset until it has an address, then releases the next module and so on. No repeaters required.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Wow, I can't believe it could be that simple!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done, but it requires that you support [multi-master arbitration](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/115577/11683) on your [I<sup>2</sup>C bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C).

In order to explain, I need to make a distictiion between your application's "system master" device and any device that may be functioning as an I<sup>2</sup>C master at a given time.

All devices, including your system master, need to be capable of operating as both I<sup>2</sup>C masters and I<sup>2</sup>C slaves.

The system master would respond (as an I<sup>2</sup>C slave) to a single reserved address. Each of the other devices, when it comes online, would execute a transaction (as an I<sup>2</sup>C master) to that reserved address to get its own slave address assignment. Thereafter, the system master would use that assigned address (as I<sup>2</sup>C master) to access that device (as I<sup>2</sup>C slave).

Comment: so, if I understand you correctly:
the system master is both a master and a slave on a reserved address. All the modules in turn first act as a master to request an address and after address assignment reset to be slave only?

Comment: Yes. The point is, you need to correctly support arbitration on the bus, because multiple devices might attempt to get their slave addresses simultaneously. In particular, you need to handle the case where they all start up in lockstep at system power-up, and prevent them from all believing that they have the *same* slave address. Each device needs to have a unique ID that is used in the arbitration process.

Comment: If each device has a unique ID already, you don't even need multi-mastering. Just have the master read the unique ID from the default address device - the slave with the first 0 bit in its unique ID will win out because the other slaves can detect that the level of the data line is not what they are trying to send. But that requires a unique ID.

Comment: @DaveTweed but that basically means I'm back at square one, as it's not really possible to assign a unique ID to the modules...

Comment: @TomCarpenter: The kind of bit-level arbitration you're talking about is a key feature of multi-master operation. It doesn't exist in normal master-to-slave transactions.

Comment: @Roland: There must be *something* that makes the modules *functionally* distinct. If not, what's the point? You can use whatever that is to also make them distinguishable on your bus.

Comment: It can exist in master-slave as long as the slaves stop sending a response if they detect bus contention. The master issues a read transaction of the unique ID to the default address. Then it sends a write transaction to the default address of a packet which includes the unique ID and new address. Only the slave with the matching unique ID would update to the new address. Essentially it is "Who's the first default device the bus, give me your ID? Ok, the device with that ID update your address".

Comment: @TomCarpenter: Yes, I understand what you are saying; I'm just saying that it isn't part of a *standard* I2C slave implementation. What you're describing would be a compatible *extension* to standard I2C, which in the OP's situation is perfectly possible.

Comment: @DaveTweed the devices do have a unique ID indeed, but wouldn't I have a problem when all modules listen to the same default address and then respond all at once?

Comment: I thought you understood my original description. It's *only the system master device* that has a default address; the other devices execute *I2C master* cycles, one at a time, to get their own unique slave addresses.

Comment: @DaveTweed Alright, makes sense. I'll see if I can figure out how to do the I2C master cycles